# Arquitetura do Computador com bat

Tags: bat

Tem o seguinte código em bat:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==X86 (echo 32 bits) else echo 64 bits
```

Esse código pega a arquitetura do processador, mas eu queria pegar a arquitetura do sistema operacional. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo informações da Microsoft contidas [neste link](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/556009), a forma correta de obter a arquitetura do sistema é o batch abaixo:

```
@echo off

Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0

REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt

Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt

If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
)
 ELSE (
    Echo "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Sim, para verificar se o sistema é 32 ou 64 bis:

Para obter com um loop **for**:

```bat
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^|find /i "bits"') do @echo/ %%a bits
```

Ou com **if exist** ainda tens outra forma:

```bat
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\" (
   echo 64 bits
  ) else (
   echo 32 bits
  )
```